# Using GetWindowText synchronously

Tags: windows, winapi

I don't quite understand how `GetWindowText` can work for a window on the same thread as the caller. If `GetWindowText` blocks until the message is processed, how can the thread call `DispatchMessage`? It's been blocked inside `GetWindowText`. Does this mean that `GetWindowText` must always be called from a separate thread from the one operating the message loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetWindowText` is just a thin wrapper for `SendMessage(WM_GETTEXT)`.

Messages sent to a window are always processed in the thread which created the window (windows have "thread affinity").  Sent messages do not go through `DispatchMessage`, rather `GetMessage` (or `PeekMessage` or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`) will call the window procedure directly, for messages sent from another thread.  If the message is sent from the same thread, `SendMessage` will call the window procedure.

---

The [`SendMessage` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) says:

> The `SendMessage` function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

And [the `GetMessage` documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx):

> Retrieves a message from the calling thread's message queue. The function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is available for retrieval.

From [the `PeekMessage` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx):

> Dispatches incoming sent messages, checks the thread message queue for a posted message, and retrieves the message (if any exist).

---

The behavior of sending messages has previously been highlighted on [Raymond Chen's excellent blog, The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/), which all Win32 developers ought to subscribe to:

> If you use any of the above send-type functions to send a message to a window that belongs to the sending thread, the call is made synchronously.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/19/266664.aspx

> Recall that `SendMessage` delivers the message directly to the window procedure; the message pump never sees it.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/23/9248851.aspx

---

And of course, there are related questions found here on StackOverflow:

- [SendMessage vs PostMessage + WaitForSingleObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779386/sendmessage-vs-postmessage-waitforsingleobject)

Comment: I saw that it worked by sending a message. I didn't read that it didn't queue the message like most messages.

Comment: @DeadMG: You've certainly contributed enough to be entitled to some basic RTFM questions, I'm just surprised you didn't know where to look for this one.